# Panda Date time Problem for Time series Analysis

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pg1WF.jpg)

I am in a fix what to do. I need year wise date time data for time series analysis (like 1974, 1975 ... 2020). But I am getting 1970 in every row. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Could you add your code and a sample data as text please.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0):

Try below formatting for date.

```
df.Period = pd.to_datetime(df.Period, format='%Y')
```

Comment: It is really helpful. Thank You so much for your kind and effective support.